# Opposite probability with different events in a single set

Tags: probability, statistics

I think I have a quite simple problem, but I just can't get it.
I'll go straightforward with an example, since I probably couldn't explain my problem in words.

EDIT:

I have different models that try to replicate a real event. At the end of the computation I will get a vector where every row is the error of a model, represented by a number greater than zero. The bigger the error, the greater is the likelihood of the model to be wrong. Then, from the errors, I compute the probability of each model to be wrong, with a simple proportion. Below there is an example with five models:

$errors = \begin{bmatrix}
500\\ 
2500\\
100\\
400\\
1500
\end{bmatrix}$; from the errors I compute the probability vector: $P = \begin{bmatrix}
0.1 \\ 
0.5 \\
0.02 \\
0.08 \\
0.3
\end{bmatrix}$

From that I would like to compute the probability of every model to be correct. How can I do? At the beginning I thought I could just compute the opposite probability for every model, but then they obviously don't add up to 1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not clear.  it appears from the data that several of your models could be correct simultaneously.  I don't see how to reconcile your numbers to the assumption that only one model is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I edited my questions, I hope it is more clear now! Thanks again

Comment: The vector of errors does not have enough information to answer your question. It can't tell, for example, if "every time model 1 erred model 5 also erred," or if "every time model 1 erred model 5 was correct."

Comment: I'm sorry @angryavian, I didn't get what you mean. I know that from the error vector I can't get a good acknowledgment of the correctness of the models, that's why I'd like to compute a probability vector that tells me how much I can trust each model. Since I can compute the probability of them to be wrong, I should compute also the probability of them to be correct. I just can't get how to do this, altough it should be quite simple.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted "the probability that models 1,2,3,4,5 are all correct simultaneously" but it seems you want "the probability that model 1 is correct, the probability that model 2 is correct, etc.". In the latter case, subtracting each of those numbers from 1 will give you the numbers you want. However, there is no reason why those numbers should add up to 1: it is like having 5 coins each with a different probability of heads, adding up the five probabilities of heads will not necessarily yield 1.

Comment: Perfect, that is where i had trouble with! You have totally right, but instead i'd like to have at the end a vector probabilities that add up to 1, so that I can say: "ok, that's the most probable model to be correct, i'd go with this one"! Yes, I know that I can still choose the best one even if they doesn't add up to 1, but I think that if I can get a probability vector that adds up to 1 with the likelihood of the models to be wrong, I should compute also a vector of probabilities adding up to 1 with the likelihood of the models to be correct, isn't it? Or am I wrong here?